# Wrong application name in push notification pop up - iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

What could be the reason that I am getting wrong application name in my push notification pop up?

Comment: A shred more detail would be good.

Comment: If you have used same push profile for two different project. Than also this will happen.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason behind this is to misplace certificate while creating `.p12` file or `.pem` file. Make sure you are choosing correct certificate while selecting in `keychain access` and following the whole process very carefully.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of places you need to make sure the app name is correct.

Within XCode:

- project and target names
- target properties (right pane)
- bundle name in build settings/info
- project name in build settings/info

In addition, you should:

- delete the Build directory
- clean the project with Cmd-Shift-k
- quit xcode and restart it
- restart your physical ios device if you're using it for testing
- delete the project directory within ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- in simulator, do iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings

I've found doing all these things works!

Comment: This helped me. Thanks.